# How do I export my OpenPGP key?

Tags: openpgp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a PGP key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100281/how-do-i-make-a-pgp-key)

I have tried the method prescribed in the Launchpad but it seems like I can't establish a connection with the key server. Using a web browser to upload the key doesn't work either. Is the keyserver down or is there any other method to upload my key?