# How do I make a PGP key?

Tags: openpgp

How do I make a [PGP key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy)? I'd like to have it for signing PPA uploads and such.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### Generating a PGP Key

Here is a GUI way to generate a new PGP key.

1. Open the *Passwords and Keys (Seahorse)* application

   *This screen will appear.*

   [image: Passwords and Keys screenshot]
2. Either go to `File` → `New` in the global menu or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
3. In the *Create New ...* window select *PGP Key* and hit *Continue*

   [image: Create New ... screenshot]
4. Enter your full name and your email address, the comment is optional

   [image: New PGP key screenshot]
5. Enter a strong password which you'll remember

   [image: Passphrase for New PGP Key screenshot]
6. Wait for the *Generating key* dialog to finish (this may take a while)
7. You're done!

You can find your key in the *Passwords and Keys* application's *My Personal Keys* tab.

[image: My Personal Keys screenshot]

### Uploading your key to Launchpad

Uploading your key to Launchpad is just a few clicks.

1. Go to [Launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net) and log in
2. On your profile page click on the yellow edit button (a round button with a grey pencil icon) next to *OpenPGP keys*

   *Note: The URL to that page looks like this `https://launchpad.net/~yourusername`*

   [image: OpenPGP keys on LP]
3. Open the application *Passwords and Keys (Seahorse)*
4. Navigate to the *My Personal Keys* tab
5. Select your key and go to `Remote` → `Sync and Publish Keys` in the global menu
6. Hit *Sync*

   [image]

   Note: The *Sync* button may be grayed out if no sync server is selected. In that case:

   - Hit the *Key Servers* button

     [image]
   - Select the `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:XXXXX` key server from the *Publish keys to* list and hit close

     [image]
7. Double click your PGP Key from the list on the *My Personal Keys* tab
8. In the key window that just appeared navigate to the *Details* tab, select the *Fingerprint* with your mouse and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

   [image]
9. Paste the just copied fingerprint into the *Fingerprint* text field on the *Change your OpenPGP keys* page on Launchpad and hit *Import Key*

   [image]
10. You're done!

Comment: Might I add that if no password is given, it will err, but give an almost-useless error?

Comment: At step 9, it can take 10 minutes before the Ubuntu server knows your key.

Comment: It just starts with "here is a GUI"  But where can I get this GUI, how can I install this GUI?

For example: sudo apt install openpgpgui
or do I need to add a new repository?

Comment: @AlexWLBI It says clearly "*Open the Passwords and Keys (Seahorse) application*"

Comment: after importing, I got a pop up message saying, an email has been sent with an encrypted key XXXXXXXXXXXXXX. I received the mail too. But how do I decrypt the message sent to me with the key XXXXXXXX provided?

Answer (score 51):

**Creating your OpenPGP keys with gpg**

Step 1: Open a terminal and type:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

Step 2: GPG will now ask you a number of questions about the type of key you want to generate. follow the steps below to select the default option each time.

Step 3: Check that your key has been generated by typing `gpg --list-keys` and, if successful.

pub   1024D/`12345678`  -> this is the important number

Step 4: **Launchpad doesn't store your key directly**, so you need to export your public key to a key server, such as keyserver.ubuntu.com:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys 12345678
```

Replace **12345678** with the pub id you noted in step 3.

If successful, GPG will display a message similar to:

```
gpg: sending key 12345678 to hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

**Importing your key into Launchpad with gpg**

Step 1: **Launchpad identifies your OpenPGP key by its fingerprint**. In your terminal, you can ask GPG for your key's fingerprint by typing:

```
gpg --fingerprint
```

GPG will display a message similar to:

```
  Key fingerprint = `0464 39CD 2486 190A 2C5A  0739 0E68 04DC 16E7 CB72`
```

copy only the numeric fingerprint: `0464 39CD 2486 190A 2C5A 0739 0E68 04DC 16E7 CB72`.

Step 2: Visit your [OpenPGP](https://launchpad.net/people/+me/+editpgpkeys)

Step 3: Paste the fingerprint that you copied in step 1 into the Fingerprint text-box, then click the Import Key button. Launchpad will use the fingerprint to check the Ubuntu key server for your key and, if successful, send you an encrypted email asking you to confirm the key import.

**Note :** this is a brief ... from launchpad process..... both process take a while so just take your time...

Comment: Step 1 may take a while if you do not have a hardware random number generator. Do not use methods which promise to speed this up because it makes your keys weaker.

Comment: If the gpg command fails to send the key to the keyserver, try pasting the result of "gpg --export -a IMPORTANT_NUMBER" to http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: Prefix the first command with `sudo` if you do not work as root. Otherwise `gpg` will not be able to store the key, and therefore key creation will fail.

Comment: browse giphy while Step 2 is generating randomness.

Comment: It may take `keyserver.ubuntu.com` 10 minutes to update. To verify, you can go to http://keyserver.ubuntu.com and search by the name or email that was used to generate the key.

Comment: In my case the gpg send-key command failed. I had to specify the protocol and port, such as hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80

Answer (score 1):

On some systems such as lubuntu where the **password and keys** (seahorse) app is not available, a good and simple way to make PGP key is using **gpa** (GNU privacy assistant). It is a graphical frontend for gpg. This method also apply to others ubuntu derivatives.

1. install gpa

> sudo apt install gpg gpa

2.launch gpa from your applications menu

[image]

3.Hit the **Keys** menu then select **New Key** . you are presented with a new window

[image]

4.Type in your full Name, click **forward**, then type in your geniune email address.press **forward**. Now select the option to **do a backup later**.

5. enter a passphrase (could be a word or phrase) to protect your PGP key
6. Now you have successfully created a pgp key. It is actually a pair, consisting of both your private key and public key
7. To use PGP in ur correspondence, for example for exchanging email securely you need to give the other party your public key. So lets first export your public key then you can send it to them. To export, open **gpa** and select your key. Now hit **Keys** menu followed by **export keys**. Give your public key a name and save it

tip: *to ensure you exported the public key, open it with a text editor and check if there is a starting line*

```
`-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`
```