# gpg key generation sync to keyserver not a key ID: skipping

Tags: gnupg, launchpad

I tried to create GPG keys

```
Real name: Political Science
Email address: @
You selected this USER-ID:
    "Political Science "

Change (N)ame, (E)mail, or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg: key 8D32FF6AEEB7BA37 marked as ultimately trusted
gpg: directory '/home/debian/.gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d' created
gpg: revocation certificate stored as '/home/debian/.gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d/980265BC6D8749B0B57526888D32FF6AEEB7BA37.rev'
public and secret key created and signed.

pub   rsa3072 2020-06-11 [SC] [expires: 2022-06-11]
      980265BC6D8749B0B57526888D32FF6AEEB7BA37
uid                      Political Science 
sub   rsa3072 2020-06-11 [E] [expires: 2022-06-11]
```

Now I do I am not able to understand which one of the above is my key which I should sync to keyserver

```
debian@osboxes:~/$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys 8749B0B57526888D32FF6AEEB7BA37
gpg: "8749B0B57526888D32FF6AEEB7BA37" not a key ID: skipping
debian@osboxes:~/$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys 32FF6AEEB7BA37
gpg: "32FF6AEEB7BA37" not a key ID: skipping
```

I am trying to do this on basis of an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/77194/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is old and you undoubtedly have found an answer by now - but to put it here, you need to put an 0x in front of the key ID: 0x8749B0B57526888D32FF6AEEB7BA37

That tells the system it is a hexadecimal number.