# Tutorials on how to generate a pgp key don't work for me

Tags: gnupg

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100281/how-do-i-make-a-pgp-key) is the second tutorial I've consulted on how to generate a pgp key.  [This was the first.](https://fedingo.com/how-to-generate-pgp-key-in-ubuntu/)  The first one downloaded the necessary program for me:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install gnupg
```

They and others all seem to agree.  But it doesn't work for me.  All the options/choices it says I'll get I don't get.  It jumps straight to having me enter my name, then eventually spits this out:

```
pub   rsa3072 2022-05-02 [SC] [expires: 2024-05-01]
```

then

```
gpg --list-keys
```

gives me nothing, which is further suspicious.

When I send to the ubuntu server, I get:

```
eriadar@eriadar-Latitude-E7440:~/pgp$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com    --send-keys rsa3072 2022-05-02
gpg: "rsa3072" not a key ID: skipping
gpg: "2022-05-02" not a key ID: skipping
```

which you predicted based on what you saw above.  I do -not- get anything like:

```
pub 1024D/12345678
```

So.. what do I do?  (if all else fails, yes, I can try a gui..)

Edit: [This tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/gpg-command-ubuntu/) more accurately shows what happens on my computer.  ..Still looking through it, it probably has the answer.

Edit: Ok, that time the ubuntu key-server accepted it.  So.. why are there tutorials with two different sets of instructions?  ..Is one set out of date?

---

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100281/how-do-i-make-a-pgp-key) is the tutorial that correctly reflects how my system actually behaves.  My key has been sent to ubuntu.  I don't know why there are two different sets of tutorials.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a PGP key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100281/how-do-i-make-a-pgp-key) - check out the other answers, not just the top one. Of course, you may not need to upload yours depending on what you're doing

Comment: @cocomac My appologies, I wasn't clear enough.  If you follow the first link I provided, it will see it's the same link.

Comment: You need to get it to give you a key when you do `list-keys`. Follow [these directions](https://askubuntu.com/a/77194/1438484), and skip everything after **Importing your key into Launchpad with gpg**. Let me know if that works

Comment: @cocomac How do you get it to give you a key when you do list-keys?  And, again sorry, but those directions are the ones I was referring to when I said I had tried the tutorial, and it hadn't worked.  I can now confirm that the last tutorial I link to -has- worked.  (so it seems) I'm going to answer my own question now.